# (Simulink) Write Data only on change

Tags: simulink

I have the following problem:

Matlab/Simulink gives me the warning:

> Warning: The block 'Data Store Write1' is writing to the data store
>   'Data Store' but the block(s) 'Data Store Write2' have already written
>   to a portion or the entire region of this memory at time t

This is because of my model looking like this:

[image]

Inside the Stateflow chart the code is:

```
[hasChanged(In)] {Out = In;}
```

So my question is:
Is there an option or something else the Data Store Write blocks are write only on change?

Annotations:

- The value "Out" is changed in the Stateflow Chart sometimes, but not in every step, and I need this "feedback" stored in Data Store. So I can read/link on the value of Data Store.
- I need to change the value from outside with the constant block.

Comment: Maybe I am simplifying your problem, but it just sounds like you need some kind of change detection / latch which can be done with basic Simulink blocks (Relational Operator, Memory...)

Comment: I don't understand your problem.
What's the aim of this model?

Comment: @amw You can't see the "aim" of this model, because it's a minimal example. With "go" I want to trigger a state inside the StateFlow chart. The state can be triggered by the StateFlow chart, too. To see if the state has changed I need it as an output of the StateFlow chart.

Comment: @Phab I would do the self triggering with internal stateflow-events. If you want it as a loop in simulink, why do you use the same DataStore?

Comment: @amw using DataStores is the only way (I found so far) I have access (read and write) to it with dSpace ControlDesk.

Comment: Try Simulink.Parameter Objects to write data from ControlDesk to model and Simulink.Signal Objects to get model data as measurement data in ControlDesk.

Comment: @amw I dont know if I understand you correctly. Do you mean arguments for starting the model via console, or are these some Simulink blocks I cant find in my library?

Comment: You can access simple C-Code Signals via ControlDesk. Just define it "x = Simulink.Signal; x.StorageClass = 'ExportedGlobal'; x.Value = 2; x.DataType = 'uint8';. Activate "ParameterInlining"-Feature. You will find the X-Variable within the "Tuneable Parameter"-Section for you ControlDesk-Variable-Tree. Same procedure for signals ("Simulink.Signal"-Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most satisfying solution I found, was to build an own 'write-only-on-change" block and add it to the library:

These three pictures show the structure of the block from outer to inner:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The subsystem is triggered on rising signals from the change detection block.
Also I added a mask to specify where to save the signal (data store/bus name).

[image]